# How do I access my parathread?

Tags: polkadot-js, rococo, parathread

I have created a parathread on Rococo [here](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rpc.polkadot.io#/parachains/parathreads), it is number 3020. It doesn't have a link or name to click to the right of it like the ones at the top do. Clicking those brings me to the page where I can interact with the parathread and call extrinsic functions. How do I do that for my parathread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to switch to you parathread's collator websocket endpoint (upper left menu), if it is running on your local machine, maybe that endpoint is (`127.0.0.1:9944`):

[image]

Comment: I want to make it so other's can use it like how I can access those top parathreads

Comment: So you have to run you collator exposed to the internet (eg. in a VPS). That way users will be able to fill the "custom endpoint" in with your collator endpoint (eg. 
 `ws://mycollator.com:9944`) and interact with it. Here is a tutorial to deploy a wss (secured websocket) in a VPS: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-wss

Comment: Oh wow. I tried deploying a parathread because I couldn't get that to work. That's unfortunate. I'm on a windows machine and for some reason I can't get my 443 port to be exposed. I guess I'll make another question since your comment resolves this one. Thank you.

Comment: Be 100% sure everything is working locally before you try anything on Rococo, as the docs try and stress. Rococo isn't a place to try out the basics as much as it is a place to get more advanced and interconnected operations tested

Answer (score 0):

You must register for a Rococo temporary slot, described here: https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/parachains/rococo/

This requires a request here:
https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Rococo&template=rococo.yaml
Then wait for the sudo holder (presently the support team at parity) to get you into the slot rotation.

More details and explanation of Rococo operations are here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pa12WrFkltc